# Better password management?

Tags: password-store

I use KeePass to manage most of my passwords, but I'm currently still storing passwords in cleartext in a few places that I'm not totally comfortable with:
+ smtp credentials in `.muttrc`
+ imap credentials in `.offlineimaprc`
+ Nextcloud credentials for caldav /cardav in `.vdirsyncer/config`

The `vdirsyncer` docs offer a few suggestions for using [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) or [keyring](https://vdirsyncer.pimutils.org/en/stable/keyring.html), but I got a few steps into the Keyring setup process and realized I'm going to have to do some troubleshooting just to get it working (I'm using Gnome, it is defaulting to a KDE wallet...). Before I go down that rabbit hole, I'm wondering if there's a reliable solution that will work for all three needs.

Comment: Make an habit of using [KeePass](https://keepass.info/)

Comment: Offlineimap can retrieve credentials from gpg files via `pass`, it is documented on the OfflineImap wiki, IIRC.

Comment: @isaac I'd love to use KeePass for this, but I wasn't able to find any guidance on how to actually use KeePass with vdirsycner, offlineimap, or mutt. If you know more about how I'd go about actually using it for this, I'm all ears.

Comment: What is your threat model? You could encrypt all or part of your home directory, but that offers no protection while you're logged in.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I'm not sure threat modeling is a useful frame here, but two solid reasons include: a) I think twice about changing passwords when I know I'm going to have to remember to update multiple random config files; b) I'd like to be able to share my config files without editing out passwords every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up going with `pass` --

My `.vdirsyncer/config` uses `password.fetch = ["command","pass","Nextcloud/user"]` to retrieve the password.

In `.offlineimaprc`

```
[general]
accounts = Example
pythonfile = ~/.offlineimap/pass.py

[Repository ExRemote]
type = IMAP
remotehost = ...
cert_fingerprint = ...
remoteuser = user@example.com
remotepasseval = get_pass("user")
ssl = yes
```

And then `.offlineimap/pass.py` includes this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2
from subprocess import check_output

def get_pass(account):
    return check_output("pass Example/" + account, shell=True).splitlines()[0]
```

I'm still fine tuning my `.muttrc` settings.